# Conditional format cells based on match in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, excel-2011

I have 2 excel sheets (Using Microsoft excel 2011 for mac, but tried the same on excel 2010 as well)

```
sheet1(Column D)
foo
bar

sheet2
abc cde foo
sfd sdf dgf
bar
```

I have applied 3 different rules using conditional format:
1. If any of the data in Sheet2 matches with Sheet1(ColumnD) - Make text as blue 
2. If there are any duplicate values in sheet2 - Make text as yellow
3. If the above 2 are not there - leave it blank
4. If both Rule 1 and Rule 22 are met - Make text as green

What can be Rule 4 ?

Rules:

```
 Rule 1 # =ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$D:$D,A1,0))=FALSE
 Rule 2 # Highlight Duplicate values with yellow text
 Rule 3 # =ISBLANK($1:$1048576)
 Rule 4 # (Not sure what to have as formula)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTIF`, in the same way excel uses count for the duplicates.

Using relative addressing to 'cheat' the system, **highlight from *A1* to where you want the formatting to stop**, then we can use the relative addressing to check each cell

Rule 1: `=(CountIf(Sheet1!$D:$D,A1)>0)`
Rule 2: `=(CountIf(Sheet2!$A:$XFD,A1)>1)` (This is what excel does when you tell it to highlight duplicates)
Rule 3: not needed, as if it doesn't match a rule, then no formatting will be applied
Rule 4: `=(AND((CountIf(Sheet1!$D:$D,A1)>0),(CountIf(Sheet2!$A:$XFD,A1)>1)))`

If you start the highlighting from any other cell, change the A1 in the rules to whatever cell you start the formatting on.

I would also recommend keeping away from using the full sheet, as it is going to get horrible performance.

Comment: @pnuts, changed to complete sheet.

Comment: When I am trying to add Rule1 , I am getting error message `You may not use unions,intersections,or array constants for Conditional Formatting criteria`.

Comment: changed sheet references to `!` - I had accidentally put a colon after the sheet name instead of the exclamation point

Comment: `Rule 4` is not working. If I place the conditions individually they are working as needed. But they are not working when I am combining them with `AND` operator. I have updated my question as well. All are working now, except `Rule 4`

Comment: I copied the formulas to a new sheet, and tested, and got everything I expected. if rule 1 and 2 are working, then copy those. you can set up a formula to copy ready for the paste into conditional formatting. put `=(AND(1,2))` into a cell, copy formula 1 over the number 1, and formula 2 over the number 2, and copy that whole formula into a new conditional format.

Comment: I did the same, but not sure why its not working.I tried changing the order of the rules as well. But its affecting Rule 1.

Comment: rule 4 will only affect rule 1 if it matches rule 2 at the same time. To test, you can move rule 4 to the top, and you will find that nothing gets highlighted in green, as the other 2 rules will override the highlighting

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question but suspect you only need two rules anyway:

1. a formula rule `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$D:$D,0)))` with blue font and
2. *format only unique or duplicate values* with `duplicate` selected, with yellow font.

Conditional Formatting will not allow a rule that returns both yellow and blue font.

---

A formula rule for say green font where both the above conditions apply, assuming the range to apply to is A:C :

```
=AND(COUNTIF($A:$C,A1),NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$D:$D,0))))
```

In some cases whether green or yellow or blue may depend upon the order the rules are applied and whether "Stop If True" is checked.

Comment: Your understanding is correct.I need one more rule to the above mentioned one. The cell that satisfies both the 2 rules with different color(say green). But I am not clear why you mentioned conditional formatting will not allow these rules? I can have separate rules right?

Comment: I want the Rule 1 to be on complete Sheet2, hence made it as `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($1:$1048576,Sheet1!$D:$D,0)))` for blue font. But its still not working